# EF DbMigration Sql update not running from embedded resource

Tags: entity-framework

Using Entity Framework 6 automated migrations, I'm trying to execute SQL from an embedded resource file using `SqlResource`.  The following script doesn't work correctly - it seems to update the column to an empty string.  It does work correctly if I run the script directly in SSMS.

```
UPDATE [EmailTemplates]
SET Html = 'xyz'
WHERE [Type] = 'ConfirmEmail'
```

If I do something simple like this it works:

```
ALTER TABLE EmailTemplates ADD SomeColumn nvarchar null
```

The "Html" column is of type `nvarchar(max) null`. Any ideas?